# Passing regular expression as a parameter in my REST webservice

Tags: java, regex, rest

What I would like to do is the pass a regular express for my 2nd parameter. For example :

- .*\\.txt
- .*2010.*\\.txt

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/filesCleanUp/{confParamName}/{pattern}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<String> doFilesCleanUp(@PathVariable("confParamName") String confParamName,
                                                     @PathVariable("pattern") String pattern)
```

This is how I call the service :

- /filesCleanUp/param1/.*\\.txt
- /filesCleanUp/param1/.*2010.*\\.txt

But it doesn't work, the pattern is not retrieve correctly from the URL. For the first one I get ".*\\" and for the second one I get ".*2010.*\\"

I did other tests with other values :

- pattern wrote in URL: \(.*l
  I got: \(
- pattern wrote in URL: (2\.[0-3]))
  I got: (2\

Usually it messed up with characters like * or .

I'm sure it's nothing but I can't find out. What I would like is to get the exact pattern I wrote

Thanks for your help

Comment: With special characters in there you're going to have to URL encode the paramater and then decode when you want to use it.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You shouldn't accept random regex from calling clients to be executed on your server - against a file system no less it looks like. In any case, if you insist on pursuing this extremely dangerous path, you need to URL encode the regex.

Comment: Can you not URL encode the regex before passing it through?

Comment: So you mean instead to pass .*\\.txt I'd better pass .*%5C%5C.txt   I tried filesCleanUp/param1/.*%5C%5C.txt in a browser and the result is exactly the same

Comment: You probably only need one backslash in front of the `.` - the double-backslash thing only applies to string literals, i.e. the Java string literal `"\\."` represents the regular expression `\.`

Comment: Yes I know deleting files with random regex from calling clients is dangerous but the service will be deploy and accessible in a very closed environment with authentication and ip restriction (only localhost) Moreover, the first parameter specified the folder defined in the database (so only folders defined in the database can be impact by the use of the webservice and files deletion). Tank you for your concerns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to pass params like this (what I strongly not recommend) please refer to 
http://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/

Otherwise encode and post them and decode back on server side.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried with this pattern (2\.[0-3])) and so with this URL : /filesCleanUp/param1/(2%5C.%5B0-3%5D))   - but still doesn't work, the server got only this part (2\

Comment: Not a Java dev, but you might want to aim for query parameters instead of splitting it like sub-resources. Hence the url should look like /filesCleanUp?confParamName=param1&pattern=(2\.[0-3]))